# Why have i not been awarded a bounty yet?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

There was a bounty of +50 rep points setup for this question: [Tags hovering like Stack Overflow using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138121/tags-hovering-like-stackoverflow-in-jquery). It ended half an hour ago. Why is it still not awarded? As far as the bounty rules are concerned the person who asked the particular question has accepted my answer before the bounty expired.

**Edit:** I was awarded +25 points by the community. Why not +50?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If bounty owner didn't select +50 icon manually, only +25 will be automatically awarded.

Comment: Ok thank you for that answer. :)